# is there away to replace a text if the year is greater than the currentYear.?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, replace

I wanna replace `"was on "` to `"will be "` if the year is greater than the `currentYear`.

```js
let myDate = new Date();
const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ];
const currentYear = myDate.getFullYear();
let tense = 'was on';
for(let year= 2020; year <= 2030; year++){
    let d = new Date(year, 4, 27);
    if(d.getDate() === 27 && d.getMonth() === 4 ){
        const output = `my birthday in ${year} ${tense} ${days[d.getDay()]}`;
        console.log(output)
    }
}
```

But when I include an `if` statement, it's returning nothing - no error, no results.

Comment: Can you include the code that didn't work?

Comment: When you have a chance, please check my solution. I replaced the need for the if/else statement with a more dynamic ternary setup, accounting for `past`, `present` (today), and `future`. I also added a second part of the output string which will output the age you were, are now, or will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let myDate = new Date();
   const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ];
   const currentYear = myDate.getFullYear();
   let tense = 'was on';
   for(let year= 2020; year <= 2030; year++){
    let d = new Date(year, 4, 27);
    if(d.getDate() === 27 && d.getMonth() === 4 ){  
       
      if(year < currentYear){
        const output = `my birthday in ${year} ${tense} ${days[d.getDay()]}`;
        console.log(output)
      }else{
       let tense = 'will be';
       const output = `my birthday in ${year} ${tense} ${days[d.getDay()]}`;
       console.log(output)
      }
    } 
}
```

Comment: wow thanks , I did this but I forgot to add else statement , I think that's why I had neither error nor output.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `if (d.getDate() === 27 && d.getMonth() === 4 ) {` if-statement? You are already manually setting the date and month values to those values of `27` and `4`, so won't that if-statement always evaluate to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const days = [
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
];
const now = new Date();
const currentYear = now.getFullYear();

for(let year= 2020; year <= 2030; year++){
    const d = new Date(year, 4, 27);
    const tense = year > currentYear ? 'will be'
      : year === currentYear ? 'is'
      : 'was';
    const dayOfWeek = days[d.getDay()];

    if(d.getDate() === 27 && d.getMonth() === 4 ){
        const output = `my birthday in ${year} ${tense} on ${dayOfWeek}`;
        console.log(output)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should be using `const` wherever possible. This is also a perfect opportunity to use a ternary operator instead of an if/else-statement.

You can also make this a bit more dynamic by determine the tense first between three values— `past`, `present`, and `future`, and then use those values to get the actual tense values you want for different part of your `desired` output statement. Then, rather than using an if/else at the end, you can just use a single `console.log` statement and let the different cases be handled by the tenses.

My example here breaks the tenses into two groups, one for the day, and one for an added age declaration I've added. For the sake of this example, I am setting the birthday to the current date, so you can see the `present` tenses in action, where the output line will read `My birthday in 2021 is today, on Friday, and I am 31 years old.`

Here is how this would look in practice:

### Iterating from birth year to 100 years later

```js
const now = new Date(),
      [currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate] = [now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()],
      bday = new Date(1990, currentMonth, currentDate),
      [bdayYear, bdayMonth, bdayDate] = [bday.getFullYear(), bday.getMonth(), bday.getDate()],
      currentAge = currentYear - bdayYear - (
        (bdayMonth < currentMonth ||
          (bdayMonth === currentMonth && bdayDate <= currentDate)
        ) ? 0 : 1
      ),
      days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
      tenses = {
        date: {
          past: 'was on a',
          present: 'is today,',
          future: 'will be on a'
        },
        age: {
          past: 'was',
          present: 'am',
          future: 'will be'
        }
      },
      _bday = new Date(bday); // cloning bday to avoid mutating the original bday date
for (let year = bdayYear; year <= bdayYear + 100; year++) {
  _bday.setFullYear(year);
  const [ month, date, day ] = [ _bday.getMonth(), _bday.getDate(), days[_bday.getDay()] ],
        previousBday = new Date(year - 1, month, date),
        age = year - bdayYear,
        dateTense =
          year < currentYear ||
          (year === currentYear &&
            (month < currentMonth ||
              (month === currentMonth && date < currentDate)
            )
          )
            ? 'past'
            : year === currentYear && month === currentMonth && date === currentDate
              ? 'present'
              : 'future',
        dateTenseString = tenses.date[dateTense],
        ageTense = age === currentAge ? 'present' : (dateTense === 'present' ? 'past' : dateTense),
        ageTenseString = tenses.age[ageTense];
  document.body.innerHTML += `<span class="${ageTense}">My birthday in <b>${year}</b> ${dateTenseString} <b>${day}</b>, and I ${ageTenseString} <b>${age} years old</b>.</span>`;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
span { padding: 5px 10px; }
span:first-of-type { padding-top: 10px; }
span:last-of-type { padding-bottom: 10px; }
span.past {
  background-color: #f8bbd0;
  color: #880e4f;
}
span.present {
  background-color: #d1c4e9;
  color: #311b92;
  border-top: 1px solid #311b92;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #311b92;
}
span.future {
  background-color: #bbdefb;
  color: #0d47a1;
}
b { font-size: 120%; }
```

This function also intelligently compares your age with your calculated age for the current year, so if your birthday has already passed this year, it will still use the `I am` tense rather than the `I was` tense. Similarly, if your birthday is yet to come in the current year, the `I am` tense will be used for the previous year's age, and this year's age tense will be `I will be`.

You could also build this into a form, like this:

### As an interactive form

```js
const inputDob = document.getElementById('dob'),
      inputYear = document.getElementById('year'),
      output = document.getElementById('output'),
      now = new Date(),
      [currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate] = [now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()],
      days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
      tenses = {
        date: {
          past: 'was on a',
          present: 'is today,',
          future: 'will be on a'
        },
        age: {
          past: 'was',
          present: 'am',
          future: 'will be'
        }
      };
const calculateAge = () => {
  const year = Number(inputYear.value),
        bdayParts = inputDob.value.split('-').map((e,i) => Number(e) - (i === 1 ? 1 : 0)),
        bday = new Date(...bdayParts),
        [bdayYear, bdayMonth, bdayDate] = [bday.getFullYear(), bday.getMonth(), bday.getDate()],
        currentAge = currentYear - bdayYear - (
          (bdayMonth < currentMonth ||
            (bdayMonth === currentMonth && bdayDate <= currentDate)
          ) ? 0 : 1
        );
  bday.setFullYear(year);
  const [ month, date, day ] = [ bday.getMonth(), bday.getDate(), days[bday.getDay()] ],
        previousBday = new Date(year - 1, month, date),
        age = year - bdayYear,
        dateTense =
          year < currentYear ||
          (year === currentYear &&
            (month < currentMonth ||
              (month === currentMonth && date < currentDate)
            )
          )
            ? 'past'
            : year === currentYear && month === currentMonth && date === currentDate
              ? 'present'
              : 'future',
        dateTenseString = tenses.date[dateTense],
        ageTense = age === currentAge ? 'present' : (dateTense === 'present' ? 'past' : dateTense),
        ageTenseString = tenses.age[ageTense];
  output.innerHTML = `<span class="${ageTense}">In <b>${year}</b>, my birthday ${dateTenseString} <b>${day}</b>, and I ${ageTenseString} <b>${age} years old</b>.</span>`;
};
calculateAge();
document.addEventListener('input', calculateAge);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
span { margin-top: 0px; }
b { font-size: 120%; }
```

```html
<label>My birthdate is <input id="dob" type="date" value="1990-01-01" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></label>
<label>What was my birthday in the year <input id="year" type="number" value="2000"></label>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This works using the ternary operator in javascript**.

```
const ripe = true;  
const egg = ripe===true? "GOOD" :"BAD";
```

**Read more here** (https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-ternary-operator/)

```
   let myDate = new Date();
   const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ];
   const currentYear = myDate.getFullYear();
   let tense1 = 'was on';
   let tense2 = "will be"
   
   for(let year= 2020; year <= 2030; year++){
        let d = new Date(year, 4, 27);
        if(d.getDate() === 27 && d.getMonth() === 4 ){  
           // If year>currentYear then(?) tense1 else(:) tense2
           const preTense = parseInt(year)>parseInt(currentYear)? tense1 : tense2;
           
           const output = `my birthday in ${year} ${preTense} ${days[d.getDay()]}`; 
    
           console.log(output)
        } 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks but this just does the vise versa but have fixed the code and its working just fine. thanks once again.

Answer (score -2):

Here you have it :)

```js
let myDate = new Date();
   const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ];
   const currentYear = myDate.getFullYear();
   let tense = 'was on';
   for(let year= 2010; year <= 2030; year++){
    
    if (parseInt(currentYear) < parseInt(year)) {tense = 'will be on';}
    let d = new Date(year, 4, 27);
    if(d.getDate() === 27 && d.getMonth() === 4 ){  
      const output = `my birthday in ${year} ${tense} ${days[d.getDay()]}`; 
       console.log(output)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why `var`, oh why?

Comment: Happy? eh, life is hard

Comment: I got another one: why are you sanitizing integers through `parseInt()`? It won't do anything.

Comment: Why don't you write some answers instead. You know, help people!

Comment: Thanks so much, God bless you. Have been stuck for hours.